# Is it possible to make yasnippets to expand snippets inside an org-mode babel section in the appropriate mode?

Tags: org-mode, yasnippet

For example I have an org mode that has the following

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp


#+END_SRC
```

Is it possible to configure yasnippets in such a way so all emacs-lisp-mode snippets can be expanded inside that block but not outside it?

Comment: I think the "standard" way would be to edit those blocks with `C-c '` anyway - in that case, the emacs-lisp major mode would have the appropriate yasnippet snippets loaded while editing the block in its separate window (that also takes care of the right indentation etc.)

Comment: Yes, I agree on VanLaser response. It works for any language supported by emacs.

Comment: Oh true. You are right. Can you put this on a response so I mark your response as correct? I didn't thought about that :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of 2017, Jan 22, if you set `org-src-tab-acts-natively` and `org-src-fontify-natively`, then TAB in source blocks will expand snippets of the block's language.  You may want to set `yas-buffer-local-condition` to stop org mode snipppets from shadowing the block mode's snippets:

```el
(defun my-org-mode-hook ()
  (setq-local yas-buffer-local-condition
              '(not (org-in-src-block-p t))))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'my-org-mode-hook)
```

---

See also https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/761, https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/pull/760

Answer (score 2):

I use two methods for this. I have some org snippets to help me create the babel headers. For example, this one creates C++-14 headers for Babel. I type `<s C++_` and expand:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: c++_header
# key: C++_
# --
C++ :main no :flags -std=c++14 -Wall --pedantic -Werror :results output :exports both
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
   $0

   return 0;
}
```

Then I use C-c ' which switches to the specific language mode and use the snippets for that language. Then use C-c ' to get back to the org file. It works well.

Answer (score 0):

As npostavs already answerered, snippets are expanded differently depending on the languages within one org-mode file.

Just type "co" and [tab] within Python or Emacs Lisp code block.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :session *Python* :results output
co[tab]
# comment
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results value scalar
co[tab]
                                        ; comment
#+END_SRC
```